# t.test error given on dataset with blank or "NA" cells

Tags: r, na, blank-line

[image of example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sd6DB.jpg)Trying to run  t.test on dataset. Data is read as .csv file. Some cells in .csv are blank (data was not collected at that site on a particular date).

When I read the .csv on R [fix(dataset)] the blank cells are blank for one site, but "NA" for other.
The t.test runs fine for the site with the 'NA' blank cells, but the site where cells are blank I receive the following error message:

"Error in var(y) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.   Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector. In addition: Warning message: In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Example code:

```
data=read.csv("WQ Analysis.csv")
fix(data)

library(dplyr)

as.factor(id)
as.numeric(US2_ln)
as.numeric(DS2_ln)    #shows "NA": for blank cells
as.numeric(DS3_ln)    # blank cells shown as blank#

ecoli=data%>%filter(id=='ecoli')     # subset data to isolate a variable 

t.test(US2_ln,DS2_ln, data=ecoli)  # Works fine ---> p-value = 0.04153 #
t.test(US2_ln,DS3_ln, data=ecoli)  # error message received #
```

Comment: Using `as.factor` or `as.numeric` doesn't change the data type unless you assign it to a variable, so it looks like your DS3_ln variable is still a factor. Add `data$id <- as.factor(id)` and so on for each of the type coercions and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Problem solved: After re-examining my data, I found that some columns had non-numeric data (e.g. "NoValue", or "-") that had been inherited when I converted my dataset from excel spreadsheet to csv.  After removing these non-numeric values from the csv file, the t-tests ran successfully without error